# Recuperando o serial do HD pelo C++ sem usar WMI

Tags: c++, windows, cmd, serial

Eu preciso pegar o MAC e o Serial do volume do HD (no cmd fica "vol C:"), eu consegui o MAC pelo codigo:

```
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {



    UCHAR MACData[6];
    char cWork[20];
    UUID uuid;
    UuidCreateSequential(&uuid); // Cria UUID do Sistema

    for (int i = 2; i < 8; i++)
    {
        //MAC começa no 2 byte até o 7, o loop copia ele
        MACData[i - 2] = uuid.Data4[i];
    }


    printf("Endereco MAC:\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        printf("%.2x ", (int) MACData[i]);
        sprintf(cWork, "%02x", MACData[i]);
        txtMAC->Text += gcnew String(cWork);
    }
    getchar();


}
```

É um evento de botão que joga o MAC em uma textbox (só pra deixar claro), e no mesmo botão como segunda função ele precisa jogar o serial do volume ("vol C:" do cmd) em outra textbox. Entretanto, o GetVolumeInformation() não funfa em nenhuma máquina que tenho em nenhuma versão do VS (fica disparando o erro C1189 "no target architecture") e não consegui resolver. :/

consegui esse código :

```
void main()
{
TCHAR szFileSys[256];
TCHAR szVolNameBuff[256];
DWORD dwSerial = 0;
DWORD dwMFL = 0;
DWORD dwSysFlags = 0;
bool bSuccess;
char fileType[255];
int bSuccessdebug = 0;
//LPCTSTR temp = _T("E:\\"); For debugging only


/*if (GetVolumeInformation(NULL, szVolNameBuff, sizeof(szVolNameBuff),
    &dwSerial, &dwMFL, &dwSysFlags, szFileSys, sizeof(szFileSys)))
    cout << dwSerial;*/




TCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };

    TCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH + 1] = { 0 };

    DWORD serialNumber = 0;

    DWORD maxComponentLen = 0;

    DWORD fileSystemFlags = 0;

    if (GetVolumeInformation(

        (LPCWSTR)("C:\\"),

        volumeName,

        ARRAYSIZE(volumeName),

        &serialNumber,

        &maxComponentLen,

        &fileSystemFlags,

        fileSystemName,

        ARRAYSIZE(fileSystemName)))

    {

            printf(("Volume Name: %s\n"), volumeName);

            printf(("Serial Number: %lu\n"), serialNumber);

            printf(("File System Name: %s\n"), fileSystemName);

            printf(("Max Component Length: %lu\n"), maxComponentLen);

    }



}// main
```

originalmente, os printf estavam assim:

```
            _tprintf(_T("Volume Name: %s\n"), volumeName);

            _tprintf(_T("Serial Number: %lu\n"), serialNumber);

            _tprintf(_T("File System Name: %s\n"), fileSystemName);

            _tprintf(_T("Max Component Length: %lu\n"), maxComponentLen);
```

ainda não entendi qual é a do _T

Tem alguma forma de resolver o C1189, pra fazer esse código rodar?

E teria como eu tratar a saída do prompt

```
system("vol C:");
```

pra jogar o resultado em uma variável sem a criação de um arquivo para tal?

Answer (score 1):

Função para pegar o Serial do HD

```
std::string StringToUpper(std::string strToConvert)
{
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < strToConvert.length(); i++)
        strToConvert[i] = toupper(strToConvert[i]);

    return strToConvert;
}

std::string GetHardDiskSerial()
{
    DWORD NumSerie;
    char NomVol[12];
    char SysFile[16];

    GetVolumeInformation("C:/", NomVol, 12, &NumSerie, NULL, NULL, SysFile, 16);

    std::ostringstream HD;
    HD << std::hex << NumSerie;
    std::string ID = HD.str();

    return StringToUpper(ID);
}
```

Comment: GetVolumeInformation não ta funfando man :/ mas ja consegui hehe fuçando nos docs da microsoft, mas obrigado pela força o/